I get two different initial css values in two different major browsers
I was developing a React component that manages a state array. For each element in this array, I used the map method to generate a list of items, which were contained within a div that had the class name .container. Each item was assigned the class .item. Here's the CSS I used:
.item {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s;
}

.container:active .item {
   opacity: 1;
}

Additionally, I attached a mousedown event listener to the container. When the user pressed the left mouse button (and before releasing it), a method would trigger to add an item to the array. This action rerendered the DOM and added a new element as a child of the container.
Here is the problem: in Chromium-based browsers, the initial opacity value for this new element is 1, even though the CSS specifies it should be 0. However, the container being "active" (due to the user pressing the mouse button) at the time of rendering might explain why its initial opacity is 1—as the CSS directs the browser to set the item’s opacity to 1 when the container is "active".
However, in Firefox, the initial opacity value is 0! Consequently, instead of interpolating the opacity from 1 to 0 as it does in Chrome, it interpolates from 0 to 1.
This results in two conflicting behaviors between the two major browsers: Chrome transitions from opacity: 1 to opacity: 0, whereas Firefox transitions from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1. I suspect this may be a browser-specific issue, but I would like to confirm this before reporting it as a bug and to explore any potential workarounds.
I have created a reproducible version of this issue here: https://playcode.io/1938075

Chromium-based browsers: Clicking inside the blue rectangle causes a new red square to appear with its initial CSS background-color set to red, transitioning to transparent upon releasing the mouse button.
Firefox: The new square initially appears transparent and transitions to red.

Thank you for considering my question!
Edit: I probably could achieve the same behavior with JS but I prefer CSS for performance reasons.
With Chrome:

With Firefox:


Clicking the container gives it the active class which is being applied to the item. What behaviour do you want to achieve?

@alex87 I would like it to behave the same in both browsers. And I like the Chromium based browsers' behavior more.

Instead of your container:active .item selector, try creating a new class and adding it to the new items

@alex87 I will try this now. Although I prefer the css way for performance reasons.

I like the Chromium based browsers' behavior more even though it's clearly wrong

@JaromandaX Yeah, you're right. I changed my mind after comparing the images.

actually, "right" is subjective :p I can see how the chrome one can make more sense if you click, rather than keep the mouse button down - it is more visually obvious what has been added

@JaromandaX Interesting take

I posted this issue in both Chromium and Firefox sites: Chromium: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/353045210 Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1907825
